# Library not loaded, for an internal private framework

Tags: xcode, frameworks, carthage

I am using Carthage.
I have a project named, **A-Framework** which has a framework inside, named **E-Framework**, with all code and a header.

In **A-Framework** -> `Linked frameworks and Libraries`

[image]
A project **a-ios** uses framework **A-Framework**. I got this at run time: 
`dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/E-Framework.framework`.

How come that main project **a-ios**, knows something about the implementation detail of the framework **A-Framework** ?